# How to MATCH within a list from vertices using Cypher queries?

Tags: postgresql, cypher, apache-age

I was attempting to match and return all vertices that contain a certain tag from within a list.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('muse', $$
CREATE(r: jazz {
name: 'Kind of Blue',
artist: 'Miles Davis',
date: '17 August 1959',
sub_genre: ['Modal Jazz', 'Cool Jazz'],
tags: ['instrumental', 'mellow', 'nocturnal', 'soothing', 'improvisation', 'progressive', 'calm'],
rating: 4.31
}) RETURN r
$$) as (jazz_record agtype);
```

```
SELECT * from cypher('muse', $$
MATCH (record)
WHERE record.tags = 'mellow'
RETURN record
$$) as (record agtype);
```

as per the official AGE documentation, there is only mention of using an index or a range.
How would I match all records that contain the tag **'mellow'** within a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT * from cypher('muse', $$
MATCH (record)
WHERE  'mellow' IN record.tags
RETURN record
$$) as (record agtype);
```

Here the `IN` clause checks if 'mellow' exists in the tags list.
Moreover, in the sample query that you have provided, use 'tags' property instead of 'tag'

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Zainab's answer, you could try the command `ANY`:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('muse', $$
MATCH (record)
WHERE 'mellow' = ANY(record.tags)
RETURN record
$$) as (record agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('muse', $$
MATCH (record)
WHERE ANY(tag IN record.tags WHERE tag = 'mellow')
RETURN record
$$) as (record agtype);
```